# Using the roots of x^3 + 2^x - 3 = 0 mod (45) in CRT to find all solutions.

Tags: number-theory

I've found the roots of congruences with respect to moduli 9 and 5.

For mod 9: the roots are 1, 2, -3

For mod 5: the roots are 1, -2.

Now my question is, how do I use the CRT to solve this system? I have 3 congruences for mod 9 and 2 congruences for mod 5, right? In other words, am I suppose to form a single congruence from each root?

Since x=1 is a root for both moduli (9 and 5), can I use x=1 in CRT to solve the entire system?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you encountered the lifting theorem before?

Comment: Nope, we haven't taken up the lifting theorem in class. However, I did see a lot of applications of the lifting theorem in such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three roots mod 9 and two roots mod 5, so the system has six solutions mod 45. Just take each pair of roots and combine with the CRT.

Yes, $x\equiv1\pmod{45}$ is a solution.

Comment: How do we have six solutions mod 45 when there are 5 roots in total? Also, am I suppose to use the CRT in a pairwise method get the solutions?

Comment: How do I set up the congruences to use the CRT? That's what I really need help on. I'd appreciate any walkthroughs. Thanks!

Comment: @user80979: You have three choices mod 9 and two choices mod 5, and 3*2 = 6. Explicitly: 1 mod 9 and 1 mod 5; 1 mod 9 and -2 mod 5; 2 mod 9 and 1 mod 5; 2 mod 9 and -2 mod 5; -3 mod 9 and 1 mod 5; -3 mod 9 and -2 mod 5.